# Laravel ManyToMany Fail

Tags: laravel

i got this function in user model

```
public function kelas(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App/Kelas','user_classes','id_user','id_class')->withTimeStamps();
}
```

i got this function in kelas model

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App/User','user_classes','id_class','id_user');
}
```

My Controller

```
public function kelas()
{
    $kelas =  Kelas::all();
    $namaguru = Auth::user()->name;
    $idlogin = Auth::user()->id;
    $kelasdiambil = User::get();
    $kelaspengajar = Kelas::all()->where("namaguru",$namaguru);
    return view('crudkelas', compact("kelas","kelaspengajar",'kelasdiambil'));
}
```

My pivot migration

```
Schema::create('user_classes', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_user');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_class');

        $table->timestamps();

        $table->primary(['id_user','id_class']);

        $table->foreign('id_user')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreign('id_class')->references('id')->on('classes')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
```

I want to create a view that show all namekelas at classes table using this pivot table with condition where id_user == Auth::user()->id ....

```
@foreach($kelasdiambil->kelas as $pel)
      <tr>
        <td><a href="ruang/{{$pel->namekelas}}">{{$pel->namekelas}}</a></td>
        <td>{{$pel->kode}}</td>
        <td><a href="/edit/kelas/{{$pel->id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a> <a href="/hapus/kelas/{{$pel->id}}" class="btn btn-danger">Hapus</a></td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
```

Error

```
Property [kelas] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: I:\darinol\nictoschool\resources\views\crudkelas.blade.php)
```

in english language, i just wanna create a user and class table became manytomany relationship and make a view to show all classname at classes table using this pivot table where the condition is id_user at pivot == Auth::user()->id; :( help me

Comment: Is there only meant to be getting one `User` (`$kelasdiambil`) from the database?

Comment: I want to display the namekelas contained in the classes table

Comment: in the pivot table there is id_user. I want to get namekelas in the table classes through this pivot where id_user is the same as the user id that is currently logged in

Comment: you have to change here `@foreach($kelasdiambil->kelas as $pel)`

Comment: i don't know changing it with what :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write like this

```
public function kelas(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Kelas','user_classes','id_user','id_class')->withTimeStamps();
}

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','user_classes','id_class','id_user');
}
```

You use collection of array

```
$kelasdiambil = User::get();
```

So You have to use like this

```
@foreach($kelasdiambil as $pel)
     <td><a href="ruang/{{$pel->kelas->namekelas}}">{{$pel->kelas->namekelas}</a></td>
```

Or you have to use like this

```
$kelasdiambil = User::first();
```

Comment: Class 'App/Kelas' not found (View: I:\darinol\nictoschool\resources\views\crudkelas.blade.php)

Comment: first `dd($kelasdiambil)` in your controller or view `{{dd($kelasdiambil)}}`. Then check this value.

Comment: i see my user table come out

Comment: i tried 
$idlogin = Auth::user()->id;
$kelasdiambil = User::all()->where('id',$idlogin);

Comment: it same.. showing user data that i need but how to access the classes table using this pivot huuhuuu...

Comment: Please check any relation first in tinker.

`php artisan tinker;` and `$user = \App\User::find(1)`  then `$user->kelas` If it works then everywhere it works

Comment: Also not found /App/Kelas

Comment: You are most welcome. This is silly mistake. And First I don't notify your problem. Then compare my code and Identify the problem. @IrvanJaya